Does h5py+MPI ("parallel HDF5") offer simultaneous writes, or just parallelized sequential writes?
I implemented a data ingestion tool in Python using h5py+MPI to ingest data from a large number of plaintest files into an equal number of HDF5 datasets. However, I'm finding that using multiple processes doesn't offer a real speedup over one process.
Does h5py+MPI actually offer simultaneous writes from separate processes? Or does it just accept parallelized "requests" to write to datasets, with the actual writes occurring sequentially?
In other words, let's say I try to write to 50 pre-created datasets from 50 processes that each have a pre-allocated random numpy array, initiating all the rights at the exact same instant. Will those 50 datasets be filled with the new random data simultaneously? Or will the writes happen sequentially, such that it's not really faster to to do the 50 writes in parallel?
Edit For clarity, I am trying to write with multiple processes in parallel to the same HDF5 file. Each write by a process is to a different dataset, and no two processes write to the same dataset. The file, groups, and datasets are created (and sized) prior to writing data to them. Writes are done independently on a per-process basis.
Thank you.

parallel hdf5 means that data can be distributed among the MPI tasks, and then written into the same file in parallel (using MPI-IO under the hood). If each MPI task writes its own data into its own hdf5 file, you only need sequential hdf5.

@GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the note, I added an edit to clarify that I am indeed using multiple processes to write to multiple datasets within a single HDF5 file.

according to https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html, populating datasets is not a collective operation, so I would assume I/O will be performed simultaneously under the hood.

@GillesGouaillardet that is what I had assumed too, but I'm finding that in practice, I'm not getting any speedup by doing so in a parallel write context, and virtually the entire runtime is expended on the specific line of code that writes (not creates+sizes) a preloaded numpy array to a dataset.
It's possible I'm doing something wrong but I don't think so, and the docs are vague and spec complex enough that at this point, I'm just hoping that somebody who knows for sure will happen to see this.

Unless you are running on a parallel filesystem (such as Lustre) and the file is stripped (multiple OSTs if Lustre) I do not think you should expect much w.r.t. speedup.

Just to rule out the file system: What performance do you get when you os.pwrite with all processes into a single file at different offsets?
